# C++20: How to wait on an atomic object with timeout?

Tags: c++, timeout, atomic, semaphore, c++20

C++20 `std::atomic` has `wait` and `notify_*` member functions, but no `wait_for`/`wait_until`.

The Microsoft STL implementation for `std::atomic` uses [`WaitOnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress) (when the OS is new enough to has it). And this API has a `dwMilliseconds` parameter just as timeout value. So from a standard library writer's standpoint, I think the missing functions are easily implementable (at least on Windows 8 or newer). I just wonder why it's not in C++20.

But as a (portable) user-code writer, I have to emulate the behavior with a standard semaphore and an atomic counter. So here's the code:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
#include <semaphore>

namespace detail
{
    template <size_t N>
    struct bytes
    {
        unsigned char space[N];
        auto operator<=>(bytes const &) const = default;
    };

    //Compare by value representation, as requested by C++20.
    //The implementation is a bit awkward.
    //Hypothetically `std::atomic<T>::compare(T, T)` would be helpful. :)
    template <std::integral T>
    bool compare(T a, T b) noexcept
    {
        static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>);
        return a == b;
    }
    template <typename T>
    requires(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T> && !std::integral<T>)
    bool compare(T a, T b) noexcept
    {
        bytes<sizeof(T)> aa, bb;
        std::memcpy(aa.space, &a, sizeof(T));
        std::memcpy(bb.space, &b, sizeof(T));
        return aa == bb;
    }
    template <typename T>
    requires(!std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>)
    bool compare(T a, T b) noexcept
    {
        std::atomic<T> aa{ a };
        auto equal = aa.compare_exchange_strong(b, b, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        return equal;
    }

    template <typename T>
    class atomic_with_timed_wait
        : public std::atomic<T>
    {
    private:
        using base_atomic = std::atomic<T>;
        std::counting_semaphore<> mutable semaph{ 0 };
        std::atomic<std::ptrdiff_t> mutable notify_demand{ 0 };
    public:
        using base_atomic::base_atomic;
    public:
        void notify_one() /*noexcept*/
        {
            auto nd = notify_demand.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (nd <= 0)
                return;
            notify_demand.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            semaph.release(1);//may throw
        }
        void notify_all() /*noexcept*/
        {
            auto nd = notify_demand.exchange(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (nd > 0)
            {
                semaph.release(nd);//may throw
            }
            else if (nd < 0)
            {
                //Overly released. Put it back.
                notify_demand.fetch_add(nd, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            }
        }
        void wait(T old, std::memory_order order = std::memory_order::seq_cst) const /*noexcept*/
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                T const observed = base_atomic::load(order);
                if (false == compare(old, observed))
                    return;

                notify_demand.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

                semaph.acquire();//may throw
                //Acquired.
            }
        }
        template <typename TPoint>
        bool wait_until(int old, TPoint const & abs_time, std::memory_order order = std::memory_order::seq_cst) const /*noexcept*/
        //Returns: true->diff; false->timeout
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                T const observed = base_atomic::load(order);
                if (false == compare(old, observed))
                    return true;

                notify_demand.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

                if (semaph.try_acquire_until(abs_time))//may throw
                {
                    //Acquired.
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Not acquired and timeout.
                    //This might happen even if semaph has positive release counter.
                    //Just cancel demand and return.
                    //Note that this might give notify_demand a negative value,
                    //  which means the semaph is overly released.
                    //Subsequent acquire on semaph would just succeed spuriously.
                    //So it should be OK.
                    notify_demand.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        //TODO: bool wait_for()...
    };
}
using detail::atomic_with_timed_wait;
```

I am just not sure whether it's correct. So, is there any problem in this code?